# How to fix FloatingActionButton inflate error in androidx for API Version 23?

Tags: java, android, floating-action-button, androidx

I am using androidx to create a basic directory app. Using a FloatingActionButton to add entries. 
The App runs perfectly on an emulator but when ran on my mobile it shows an android.view.InflateException.

The Error -

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.vestige.directory2, PID: 10648
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.vestige.directory2/com.vestige.directory2.Activities.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2545)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2605)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:165)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:179)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5730)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:681)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.vestige.directory2.Activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:51)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6439)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2498)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2605) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:165) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:179) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5730) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:681) 
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
        at com.vestige.directory2.Activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:51) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6439) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2498) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2605) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:165) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:179) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5730) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:681) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
        at com.vestige.directory2.Activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:51) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6439) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2498) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2605) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:165) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:179) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5730) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:681) 
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.vestige.directory2:drawable/ic_plus_white" (7f07006b) is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f07006b a=-1 r=0x7f07006b}
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2798)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2732)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870)
        at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:152)
        at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:84)
        at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:80)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.VisibilityAwareImageButton.<init>(VisibilityAwareImageButton.java:45)
        at com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:192)
        at com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:188)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
        at com.vestige.directory2.Activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:51) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6439) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2498) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2605) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:165) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:179) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5730) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:681)
```

FloatingActionButton XML (This code is from line 26 as in the error.)-

```
 <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_plus_white" />
```

MainActivity Code -

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);

        fab.setOnClickListener(v -> addInformation());
```

I have referred many solution and mostly all of them talk about changing android:backgroundTint to app:backgroundTint which as you can see I am not even using.

My `build.gradle(Module: app)` dependencies -

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    // Room components
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$rootProject.roomVersion"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$rootProject.roomVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$rootProject.roomVersion"

    // Lifecycle components
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$rootProject.archLifecycleVersion"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$rootProject.archLifecycleVersion"

    //Gson
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
}
```

My styles.xml -

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Light" />

</resources>
```

ic_plus_white.xml -

```
<vector android:height="23dp"
    android:viewportHeight="512"
    android:viewportWidth="448"
    android:width="20dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FFF"
        android:pathData="M416,208H272V64c0,-17.67 -14.33,-32 -32,-32h-32c-17.67,0 -32,14.33 -32,32v144H32c-17.67,0 -32,14.33 -32,32v32c0,17.67 14.33,32 32,32h144v144c0,17.67 14.33,32 32,32h32c17.67,0 32,-14.33 32,-32V304h144c17.67,0 32,-14.33 32,-32v-32c0,-17.67 -14.33,-32 -32,-32z" />
</vector>
```

API Version on Emulator 28

API Version on Mobile 23

**SOLVED**: Just had to move my drawable ic_plus_white.xml from drawable-v-24 folder to drawable folder. Solved the issue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure your app or the activity theme inherits one of the following themes:

- Theme.MaterialComponents
- Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar
- Theme.MaterialComponents.Light
- Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar
- Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar
- Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight
- Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar
- Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar

It seems your `drawable/ic_plus_white` is not a valid drawable. Please verify it's content too.

Comment: I have updated the question with my `styles.xml`, and I think I have done that too.

Comment: what about `drawable/ic_plus_white` ? Can you share that too?

Comment: yes okay, I'll update the question with it? But I don't know if that can be a reason for error as it is just a vector asset.

Comment: Can you try adding a different drawable, maybe not a vector drawable if it works? because the error seems related to your vector drawable.

Comment: Thanks that solved the problem!! My drawable was in drawable-v-24 folder, and I moved it in drawable folder. Works like a charm! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're having is on line 26 of the launching activity XML. if you can show us that file we may be able to help.

Comment: FloatingActionButton xml is the xml code from line 26 in my `main_activity.xml`